# Trouble with validating PHP Password via MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation

I am working on a project that I've run into a what I think is a simple fix., I just am not seeing it.

You can look at the live site at www.thriftstoresa.com the issue is with the login page (http://www.thriftstoresa.com/Login.php)

A valid username is 'none' and it's password is 'password'.

The issue I am having is I always return 'Incorrect password, please try again.'

Any assistance would be appreciated. As you can probably tell, I'm new to PHP. Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Acme Online</title>

<script src="formenhance.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
p.MsoNormal {
margin:0in;
margin-bottom:.0001pt;
font-size:12.0pt;
font-family:Cambria;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body> 
<?php   // Connect to Database   
mysql_connect(LEFT OUT OF THE CODE ON PURPOSE) or die(mysql_error());   
mysql_select_db( 'thriftstoresa.com') or die(mysql_error());   

//Checks if there is a login cookie
 if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
 //if there is, it logs you in and directs to the catalog page
 { 
$username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
$pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acme WHERE Username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
    {
    if ($pass != $info['password']) 
        {
                    }
    else
        {
        header("Location: catalog.php");
        }
    }
 }

 //if the login form is submitted 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
 // makes sure they filled it in
    if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
        die('You did not fill in a required field.');
    }

 // checks it against the database
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acme WHERE Username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or      die(mysql_error());

 //Gives error if user doesn't exist
 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
 if ($check2 == 0) {
        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=contact.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
            }
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     
 {

 $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

 //gives error if the password is wrong
    if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
        die('Incorrect password, please try again.');
    }
 else 
 { 

 // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
$_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
$hour = time() + 3600; 
setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);   

//then redirect them to the members area 
header("Location: contact.php"); 
 } 
} 
} 
else 
{
 // if they are not logged in   
 ?>   


<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="leftcolumn">
    <nav id="navigation"><li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="catalog.php">Catalog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section id="main">
    <div align="center"><img src="images/ACMELogo.png" width="225" height="70" alt=""/></div>
    <article id="catalogofitems">
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;border:none;padding:0in;"><span     style="font-family:Arial;">Please Log In</span></p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;border:none;padding:0in;">&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;border:none;padding:0in;"><span     style="font-family:Arial; ">____________________________________</span></p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Times;     ">&nbsp;</span></p>

      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

        <p><strong>Member Login</strong></p>
        <p>
          <label for="textfield">Username:</label>  
          <input name="username" type="text" size="25" maxlength="22">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" size="25" maxlength="22">

        </p>
        <p>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Login"  value="Login">
      </form>   <?php   }     ?>
        </p>
        <p><strong><a href="contact.php">Create an Account</a></strong></p>
      </form>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;</p>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
        <div align="center"></div>
      </form>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Times; font-size:8.0pt; ">ACME Corp</span></p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Times; font-size:8.0pt; ">Trademark of the ACME Company and Distribution</span></p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Times; font-size:8.0pt; ">1920-2013, a part of  Road Runner Conglomerate</span></p>
      <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center;"></p>
    </article>
  </section>
      <section id="rightcolumn"><img src="images/Wiley_ACME_LOGO.jpg" width="315" height="234" alt=""/>        </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a `|` missing in `$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass'])` which should read as `$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['pass'])` - Start with that.

Comment: You should never tell an unauthenticated web site visitor whether it's the username or the password that's incorrect.  Also, `mysql_num_rows()` has been known to be unreliable before you fetch the result set. Also, what is the datatype of the `password` column in your `acme` table, and how are those values set when a user changes her password? Also, please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and please consider discontinuing the use of `md5()` for password hashing. It's trivial to crack these days.

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- I missed that. And Ollie Jones, the datatype is Varchar

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Please, **DO NOT** write your own authentication layer. Instead use 
[a development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
which comes with an [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: This is horribly insecure. You should be using SESSION rather than cookies for keeping track of if the user is logged in (because SESSION resides on the server, whereas cookies can be manipulated client-side).  And you should set that the user is logged in into the SESSION before redirecting, and check that session variable in every page.

Comment: Also, why are you using a `while` loop to loop through the resultset for username rather than an `if` in checking the password? Obviously usernames should be unique.  If you don't have the `unique` constraint on the username field in your database, then wow.

Comment: And why are you reading the db to check the password twice?  I suggest you rewrite this whole thing from scratch and think it out better this time.

Comment: The mysql interface is deprecated (that is, the functions starting with `mysql_`). New development should use either the **`mysqli`** interface or **`PDO`**.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I realized I was looking at some real old tutorials and have since changes over to secure registration with session support. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using something like https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth . The code which you have shown is inviting more issues as already mentioned by tadman in comment.

Answer (score 0):

So I will point out a few things I see that might help you. First of all if your just learning `php` then forget mysql and learn mysqli. As it will no longer exist in newer php versions.
That being said lets take a look at what you got.

```
//cookie only when they have entered in a correct login and password
$username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
$pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
//needs to have another `|`
if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['pass']) {
//here your checking md5($_POST['password']) against $info['password']
if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) { //is info password md5() hashed?
```

here is a suggestion this might save some time on your code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=\"".$email."\" AND md5(password)=\"".md5($password)."\"";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0) 
    {
        echo "Incorrect Login";
    }
    else 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        //set your cookies here
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
        $_SESSION['user_id-'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]=mysql_result($query,0);
        //set a session of logged in by your server name and mysql_result and i would use an identifying ID number for every user.
        echo "Successfully Logged In";
    }
//to check if some one is logged in
if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id-'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']])) redirect("index.php?action=alreadyloggedin");
//session variable can be w/e you want
```

i also would not use md5 and rather sha1